# Simple example of not a Banach space. Product topology.

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Claim:
$$R^\infty \text{ is not a Banach space when equipped with its natural product topology}$$
I need help proving this 'obvious' claim. I just got acquainted with a definition of a product topology and the concept does not seem to be easy to work with. How would I even go about showing whether $R^\infty$ is metrizable?

**Edit:**
Intuitively, I know that $$d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|x_j-y_j|}{1+|x_j-y_j|}$$
should prove that $R^{\infty}$ is metrizable.

Comment: Off-hand, I'm not sure about the question you ask. But are you also asking for a proof of the claim, or are you fine with that?

Comment: I am asking for a proof of a claim. Sorry for omitting it, I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: any basic neighbourhood of $0$ in the product topology will contain a straight line through $0$.

Comment: what is 'basic'? are you assuming convexity?

Comment: A basic neighbourhood of $0$ in the product topology of ${\mathbb R}^\infty$ is $\prod_{j \in N} U_j$ where all but finitely many $U_j$ are $\mathbb R$ and the others are arbitrary neighbourhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb R$.  Convexity is not relevant here.

Comment: That's pretty much the standard definition of the product topology.  If you prefer to use your metric, the hint still works: show that $\{x: d(x,0) < \varepsilon\}$ contains a straight line through $0$.

Comment: I was just wondering whether basic neighbourhood was different to a neighbourhood. I understand why it has a line segment, thank you. Should I try to show that $R^{\infty}$ is not complete or that there's no norm?

Comment: Show that for every norm, the unit ball does not contain a straight line through $\mathbf{0}$. $\hspace{0.8 in}$

Comment: if $\{tv,t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset B(0,1)$ for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, just take $t > 1/||v||$ to conclude there's no line.